# How to assign public port to port 5900 in docker-compose

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I have below YAML file :

seleniumhub:

```yaml
image: selenium/hub

ports: 
 - 4444:4444
```

firefoxnode:

```yaml
image: selenium/node-firefox-debug  

ports:
 - 4577

links: 
 - seleniumhub:hub 

expose: 
 - "5900"
```

chromenode:

```yaml
image : selenium/node-chrome-debug

ports:
 - 4578

links:
 - seleniumhub:hub

expose: 
 - "5900"
```

---

docker ps:

```
time="2017-04-01T17:57:44+03:00" level=info msg="Unable to use system certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
9d2ccb193b54        selenium/node-firefox-debug   "/opt/bin/entry_po..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        5900/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32785->4577/tcp   dockercompose_firefoxnode_1
4be6223fe043        selenium/node-chrome-debug    "/opt/bin/entry_po..."   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        5900/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32784->4578/tcp   dockercompose_chromenode_1
7d95d3e73016        selenium/hub                  "/opt/bin/entry_po..."   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:4444->4444/tcp              dockercompose_seleniumhub_1
```

---

But whenever I run below command in Docker quick start terminal:

```
docker port 9d2ccb193b54 5900
```

I got below:

> Error: No public port '5900/tcp' published for 9d2ccb193b54

and I'm not able to connect to the node machines through VNC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `firefoxnode` try this configuration:

```
image: selenium/node-firefox-debug  

ports:
 - 4577
 - 5900

links: 
 - seleniumhub:hub 

expose: 
 - "5900"
```

`expose` does not publish port to the host machine and only accessible to linked services. It works for inter-container communication. `ports` will expose that port to host machine.

Answer (score 0):

For exposing ports the syntax is:

```
ports:
  - "host:container"
```

In your case:

```
image: selenium/node-firefox-debug  

ports:
 - 4577
 - "5900:5900"

links: 
 - seleniumhub:hub
```